# editing a folder outside the root with Dreamweaver (or other software)

Tags: php, dreamweaver, root

I use a Windows-based home control software called "IP-Symcon". At its core, it is a scheduler/spooler that uses PHP to control all kinds of appliances. In addition, it offers a web server that exposes the directory "C:\IP-Symcon\Webfront\User". All Symcon-specific variables and commands are available to the internal web site as well.

I use Dreamweaver to build everything in the yellow site. There is stuff that records temperature, wind, and rain, a postgres interface for archiving, and Jquery stuff for visualization.

The problem is the blue directory (C:\IP-Symcon\scripts). That directory contains all the IP-Symcon internal scripts, which are all in PHP. I would like to use Dreamweaver for that as well, since the internal IP-Symcon editor is beyond pathetic. However, that directory is outside the web site, and hence off limits. Is there a way to convince Dreamweaver to incorporate a folder that is outside the web root?

[image]

Comment: do you want to reference the folder from your code or you want the folder to be browsable from dreamweaver (listed in File Explorer)?

Comment: Referencing from the code works with absolute paths - which is usually frowned upon, but here I think I have no alternatives. Having the blue folder browsable, editable, and testable within the "Dreamweaver ecosystem" would be great - but I cannot seem to be able to find a way to do that.

Comment: In the file explorer (F8 or Windows->Files) there is a dropdown where you can select sites, I think you can browse your file system also by select "desktop" or "local drive (C:" or something. Will this help?